# Comment likes API available for Bitbucket hosted on premises

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api, bitbucket-server

I wonder if we should be able to access this comment likes api if our Bitbucket is a server hosted on premises?

https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/bitbucket-server/4.8.1/bitbucket-comment-likes-rest.html#idm34960

I can't find this api from our rest browser for the bitbucket api.

Our Bitbucket Server version is v4.13.0

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That API is for Bitbucket Server (the on-premise version), just for an older version than what you're using. Does https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/bitbucket-server/4.13.0/bitbucket-comment-likes-rest.html#idm45451308864416 work for you?